# Корректировка shortcut'ов Explorer'а

Tags: windows, explorer

Возникла следующая проблема:
Мне необходимо изменить вид окна Explorera, открываемого по "Win+E" таким образом, чтобы слева не отображалась панель с деревом папок и не насиловала мои глаза.

Я делал некоторые попытки разобраться в этом вопросе, вот что в итоге имеется:

1. Насилующая глаза панель - следствие
       запуска explorer'а с параметром /e
2. Шорткат обрабатывается процедурой
       одного из окон Explorer'а: либо
       окном класса "SHELLDLL_DefView",
       либо "Progman", определить, каким
       именно, мне не позволил скилл.
3. Пытался отследить ключи реестра,
       читаемые Explorer'ом при загрузке -
       не нашел подозрительных.

Хотелось бы найти решение с модификацией реестра или патчем чего-нибудь о_о.
Прошу не предлагать использовать хуки или готовый софт на хуках типа AutoHotkey. Мои убеждения строго запрещают мне так поступать в этом случае. Заранее спасибо!

P.S. ОС: Windows XP SP2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть возможность самомстоятельно настроить поведение системы в этой ситуации. Если удалить ключ HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\explore\ddeexec
(на функционировании системы это никак не отражается, поскольку этот ключ дополнительный), то значение параметра по умолчанию в ключе
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\explore\command
будет определять коммандную строку открытия окна проводника по сочетанию клавиш Win+E. Причём на функционировании пункта контекстного меню папок "&Проводник" это никак не отражается, продолжает открываться новое окно Проводника с левой панелью дерева папок и открытой соответствующей папкой.
Я присвоил параметру по умолчанию в ключе command значение "explorer.exe D:\", и теперь у меня при нажатии Win+E открывается корневой каталог диска D:\ без левой панели. Удаление или запрет ключа HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\explore
приводит к тому, что горячие клавиши Win+E перестают функционировать.